# XML File Validation Against Azure SQL Server in Azure Data Factory

Tags: xml, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

**My XML File** (LOCATED IN Azure Blob Container)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Details xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Person>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>XXX</name>
    <age>12</age>
  </Person>
</Details>
```

**My Azure SQL Server Table**

**Table Name :** UserTABLE

```
ID   | NAME | AGE | GENDER    
1    | JAY  | 12  |  MALE
2    | XXX  | 11  |  MALE
```

I want to compare the  from XML file against the Above Azure SQL server (UserTABLE),if  Matches then i want to **Update** other fields from the *XML file to my UserTable*, if not then i want to **insert as a new row** in the Azure SQL Server with all the given fields values from *XML to my UserTable*

Can anyone please suggest me how can i proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL Database has recently gained the ability to load files from Azure Blob Storage using either BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET. Start [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/02/23/loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database/).

Taking your example code and data, you could import the xml, shred it, then use `MERGE` to `INSERT/UPDATE` it into your main table.  A simple demo:

```
DROP TABLE staging 
DROP TABLE #tmp
DROP TABLE yourTable

CREATE TABLE staging ( rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, yourXML XML );
CREATE TABLE #tmp ( id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, age INT NOT NULL );

SELECT * INTO yourTable FROM #tmp

INSERT INTO staging
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'archive/temp.xml',
    DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorageAccount',
    SINGLE_BLOB
) AS x


INSERT INTO #tmp ( id, name, age )
SELECT
    x.c.value('(id/text())[1]', 'int' ) AS id,
    x.c.value('(name/text())[1]', 'varchar(30)' ) AS name,
    x.c.value('(age/text())[1]', 'int' ) AS age
FROM staging s
    CROSS APPLY s.yourXML.nodes('Details/Person') AS x(c)


-- Merge
MERGE INTO dbo.yourTable t
USING
(
SELECT * FROM #tmp
) s ON t.id = s.id

-- Insert new records ( no match on primary key )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN 
        INSERT ( id, name, age )
        VALUES ( id, name, age )

WHEN MATCHED 
        AND t.name != s.name
         OR t.age != s.age

-- Update existing ( no match on primary key )
THEN UPDATE 
        SET
            t.name = s.name,
            t.age = s.age;


SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable
```

The best thing for you to do is forget about Data Factory for a moment. Write a SQL script that successfully does the setup for the above and runs successfully. When you've got that working, covert it to a stored proc. Test it. When you've got that working, you can start to think about Data Factory. You will need an output dataset, but not an input one.  Work through the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-stored-proc-activity).

Comment: Can i use your Answer in my Storeprocedure?.I mean my Datafactory consist of input data set as **Blob Storage** Where XML data Resides, then my Store Procedure Activity as **pipeline** contains your code ,which will do the insert and update in my table.

Comment: Yes, I think you could simplify this into a single stored procedure which does all the work, no XML dataset required.

Comment: Oh,No input dataset required ! I'm thinking each pipeline must contain a input/output dataset. So as you say no dataset (input/output) required for my solution ? A single StroeProc Pipeline Enough without any datasets?

Comment: Forget about Azure Data Factory for a moment.  Write a SQL script that successfully does the setup for the above and runs successfully.  When you've got that working, covert it to a stored proc.  Test it.  When you've got that working, you can start to think about Data Factory.  You will need an output dataset, but not an input one.

Comment: Ok thanks @wBob,i will check your code and let you know its working or not

Comment: Yes It's Working Perfect within SQL Server.Need to find further about to implement in Data Factory :)

Comment: I'm having a doubt here my file is in Azure Blob Container.So each and every time i need a SAS token to Load the xml file ? Is there is any way to Skip the SAS token generating part ?

Comment: According to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql) a Shared Access Signature (SAS) is required to import a file from Azure Blob Storage as at today.  However the SAS is set at Storage Account level and you set the time limit, permissions etc

Answer (score 2):

you can use a staging table where you will truncate/load the xml data and then call a stored proc from same ADF to do Insert/Update based on this staging data in your staging table. During next run, it will truncate the table and then do the same process again. All this can be done through your existing ADF.